# Is it possible to use a type defined with "typedef enum" in a module's port declaration?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understand how typedef and enum work in SystemVerilog and, in particular, if it's possible to use a "custom" data type in a module's port declaration.

So far, I've been able to create a custom data type in a package, here it is:

```
typedef enum logic[2:0] {
        add_conf = 3'b000,
        sub_conf = 3'b001,
        and_conf = 3'b010,
        or_conf = 3'b011,
        xor_conf = 3'b100,
        sll_conf = 3'b101,
        srl_conf = 3'b110,
        sra_conf = 3'b111
} iexu_conf
```

Now, I'd like to define an input port of type `iexu_conf` in a module, like this:

```
module iexu_decoder
(
    input iexu_conf conf,
    output logic add_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] logic_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] shifter_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] outmux_ctrl
);
```

Is this possible? If so, is the syntax correct? I'm currently getting problems with Modelsim

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) iexu_decoder.sv(5): near "conf": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ')'.
```

but I can't tell if it's because of some stupid mistake or if it's due to a more serious conceptual error.

Comment: yes it is possible. which compiler did you use? did you compile in system verilog mode? you are missing semicolon after typedef decl. are there other errors?

Comment: I did not copy-pasted the semicolon but it's there, I'm using ModelSim - Intel FPGA Edition vlog 10.5b Compiler. Matter of fact, I did not import correctly the package, so no wonder the compiler didn't recognize the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the `typedef` in a package, you need to explicitly reference the package or `import` it to be visible in all module declarations that use it.

```
package pkg;
  typedef enum logic[2:0] {
        ...
  } iexu_conf;
endpackage
```

Explicit reference:

```
module iexu_decoder
(
    input pkg::iexu_conf conf,
    output logic add_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] logic_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] shifter_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] outmux_ctrl
);
```

Module header import:

```
module import pkg::*; iexu_decoder
(
    input iexu_conf conf,
    output logic add_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] logic_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] shifter_ctrl,
    output logic[1:0] outmux_ctrl
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the fact that I didn't import the package correctly. I thought that `include "constants.sv" did the trick, I was wrong.